# Are all seasons of 'Suits' interconnected?

Tags: suits

I want to know if all seasons of **Suits** are interconnected as I haven't watched one. And thus, can I watch **season 6** without seeing pre-aired seasons.

Comment: Yes they are, to some degree. But why would you watch S6 without watching S1-S5 first? And if S1-S5 aren't available to you, why bother with S6? There's sooooo much to watch, why bother with watching a show from S6 on?

Comment: Basically: The first episode establishes the whole story and the whole "secret/problem" they'll have to keep during all seasons. Seasons finish with a cliffhanger that will be resolved in the beginning of the next season. In a season, there is a plot for the episode, but also another one in background for a few episodes or the whole season. There are humans relationships, and you may want to know why some people hates each others, or why they protect others, why treason occured, etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Well, you know what, fortunately the reasons why the asker asked his question *don't really matter at all*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each season heavily follows on from the previous.

You need to see all the series from the beginning to get most of the drama outside the cases themselves.

Most importantly you need to see the pilot because otherwise you'll have no appreciation for the entire premise of the show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the seasons of 'Suits'are interconnected. The premier season would let you in on the central theme and you'll need to watch each and every episode so as to not miss out on the intricate details. I think this would keep you hooked and help you enjoy, appreciate the show better.